# ngrx/store selector returns function instead of object

Tags: angular, ngrx, reselect

I am following the example-app (https://github.com/ngrx/example-app), all my stores, effects, actions are working great but I am getting weird behaviour when using selector defined in the reducer file vs selector defined in the container file.  The selector defined in the reducer file returns the function whereas the selector defined in the container file returns the object.  I have copied code snippet to explain this in details.  I would like to define the shared selector hence it is easy to maintain and upgrade easily instead of defining in the container component every time. I appreciate if someone shed some light to resolve this issue.

//package.json

```
{
    dependencies: {
        "@angular/common": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/core": "2.2.1",
        "@angular/forms": "2.2.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.0.0-beta.12",        

        "@ngrx/core": "^1.2.0",
        "@ngrx/effects": "^2.0.0",
        "@ngrx/store": "^2.2.1",
        "@ngrx/store-devtools": "^3.2.3",
        "reselect": "^2.5.4"        
        ....
    },
}
```

//space.reducer.ts
//space interface and reducer

```
export interface SpaceState {
    lastUpdated?: Date,

    spacesLoaded: boolean,
    spaces: {[key: string]: Space}
}

export const INITIAL_STATE: SpaceState = {
    lastUpdated: new Date(),

    spacesLoaded: false,
    spaces: {},
};

export const getMap = (state: SpaceState) => state.spaces;
```

//application.reducer.ts
//composed state interface and reducer

```
import * as fromSpace from "./space.reducer.ts";

export interface ApplicationState{
    spaceState: SpaceState
}

export const INITIAL_APPLICATION_STATE: ApplicationState = {
    spaceState: fromSpace.INITIAL_STATE
};

const reducers = {
    spaceState: fromSpace.reducer
};

const reducer: ActionReducer<ApplicationState> = combineReducers(reducers);

export function reducer(state: any, action: any) {
    return reducers;
}

export const getSpaceState = (state: ApplicationState) => state.spaceState;
export const getSpaceMap = (state: ApplicationState) => createSelector(getSpaceState, fromSpace.getMap);
```

//spaces.container.ts
//container component

```
export class SpacesComponent implement onInit() {
    constructor(private store: Store<ApplicationState>) {}

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.store.select(getSpaceMap).subscribe(map => {
            console.log("subscribe of space-map (using shared func) from container: " + map);
        });

        this.store.select((state) => state.spaceState.spaces).subscribe(map => {
            console.log("subscribe of space-map (using container func) from container: " + map);
        });
    }
}
```

//output from container

```
subscribe of space-map (using shared func) from container: function selector(state, props) {
      for (var _len4 = arguments.length, args = Array(_len4 > 2 ? _len4 - 2 : 0), _key4 = 2; _key4 < _len4; _key4++) {
        args[_key4 - 2] = arguments[_key4];
      }

      var params = dependencies.map(function (dependency) {
        return dependency.apply(undefined, [state, props].concat(args));
      });
      return memoizedResultFunc.apply(undefined, _toConsumableArray(params));
    }

subscribe of space-map (using container func) from container: [object Object]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're calling what appears to be reselect's `createSelector` in your `getSpaceMap` selector and you are returning its result, which is why it is returning a function. Your selector is returning another selector.

Instead, you should assign the result of `createSelector` to `getSpaceMap`:

```js
export const getSpaceMap = createSelector(getSpaceState, fromSpace.getMap);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it helps and resolved the issue.  My bad cut and paste caused this problem :(